# how to refresh div content using jquery

Tags: jquery

I know the answer is pretty simple but i'm kinda stuck right now.So this is the code that displays  JSON values on my page using the id selectors.Now everytime the result is obtained the content of the divs arent refreshed but appended with the new result?

```
.done(function(data) {
        // Get face rectangle dimensions
        var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
        var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');

        // Append to DOM
        for (var prop in faceRectangle) {
            faceRectangleList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>");
        }

        // Get emotion confidence scores
        var scores = data[0].scores;
        var scoresList = $('#scores');

        // Append to DOM
        for(var prop in scores) {
            scoresList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>")
        }
```

What i want is to refresh the contents so only the new results are displayed.

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.append()`. the append command _appends_ things to the end of the element (clue's in the name!), while `html()` (less obvious name, but actually logical, when you consider there is also `text()`) _replaces_ the whole content of the element. N.B. At the moment you are looping multiple append commands, instead of that create a string variable, add to it gradually, and then use that variable in one single "html" command at the end (I mean one for each of your different elements that you're populating).

Comment: Seems right but i'm new to coding so can you provide a code example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html() instead of append().

```
.done(function(data) {
        // Get face rectangle dimensions
        var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
        var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');

        // Append to DOM
        for (var prop in faceRectangle) {

              // here i replace append with html

            faceRectangleList.html("<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>");
        }

        // Get emotion confidence scores
        var scores = data[0].scores;
        var scoresList = $('#scores');

        // Append to DOM
        for(var prop in scores) {
            scoresList.html("<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>")
        }
```

or you can do like this,

```
// Append to DOM
Var str = “”;
for (var prop in faceRectangle) {

            str += "<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>";
        }
faceRectangleList.html(str);
```

append() is working as same as when you do,

```
String s = “my name is : “;
S +=”dilusha”;
```

html() just clear the current content and put your new content to the element. (This is not how they originally works. But seems like this is more understandable for beginner)

view [jquery.html(htmlString) api referance](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: But i am displaying JSON data and i have four lines of data.If i use .html it just displays the first line of result and refreshes it.

Comment: See the above comment of ADyson.Can you provide in code what he is trying to say.I think thats the correct solution

Comment: Var str = “”;

for (var prop in faceRectangle) {

            str += "<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>";
        }

faceRectangleList.html(str);

Comment: add all values to string variable and parse it to html() after the for loop ends.see the edited answer